# What to do when a page belongs under two primary navigation sections

Tags: navigation

More of an information architecture question, but here goes...

I have a page the belongs under two different primary navigation nodes equally.  At least that's what the user feedback pointed to. But I was wondering what other professionals are doing / would do in this situation.

To paint a clearer picture, the two primary navigation elements are as follows

- Special Events
- Education

The secondary pages under the "Special Events" sections lists a series of unique events. The "Education" section lists classes, certificates and other educational related topics.

The secondary page I am referring to (actually there are a few of pages like this) is unique because it's an event that is approved for continuing education credit, which is very important to our visitors education goals). But at the same time, it's nothing nothing like our regular classes or certificate offerings.

Our feedback stated, it's very important to list these events under the "education" section because a lot of people are only interested in Education.  But at that same time, because of how unique the event is, people will want to participate whether they get credit or not and it should also be placed under the "Special Events" section with the rest of the special events.

My first thought is to simply duplicate the page under both sections, such as:

- Special Events

  - Awesome Event 1
  - Awesome Event 2
  - Awesome Educational event series (the following events appear on the one page)

    - event 1
    - event 2
    - event 3
- Education

  - Classes
  - Certificates
  - Awesome Educational event series (the following events appear on the one page)

    - event 1
    - event 2
    - event 3

but I'm also not crazy about the idea of duplicating content if there was a way to better organize it.

Thoughts?

Comment: pages get duplicated all the time.  are you worried because you're displaying the duplicate page titles in the same navbar?

Comment: Not the same navbar.  They would be duplicated like in the example above.  But that's good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pages are often duplicated on websites.

- A camera product page may exist under `electronics`, `on sale`, and `recommended for you` links on a site.
- A university quantitative economics course may exist under the `economics`, `mathematics`, and `visiting professors` sections of a school website.

There are some issues to resolve if you decide to do this:

- Use the same or different URLs for the duplicate pages?
- Make sure any navigation breadcrumbs or back links are handles correctly
- If using a navbar, make sure the navbar doesn't jump sections awkwardly